# A river flows south with a velocity of 2m/s. A man steers his boat across the river with a velocity of 4m/s to east relative to the river.

Tags: kinematics

Find the orignal velocity of the boat

MY SOLUTION:

Let’s assume coordinate axes along the conventional directions, where +x is in east and +y is north (although it’s relatively unimportant)

Since the relative velocity of boat wrt to river is 4j and 
$$V_{AB}=V_A-V_B$$
So 
$$4j=V+2i$$where v is the actual velocity of the boat.
$$V=4j-2i$$
$$V=\sqrt{20}$$
$$V=2\sqrt5$$

The answer given is $4\sqrt5$, which I highly doubt is wrong, but I needed to confirm it nonetheless. I know it’s an extremely simple question, but I needed to get it verified.

Thank a lot!

Comment: The answer should in fact be $2\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Your answer is right!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I always need to check if I am right or wrong, cause I cant trust myself